# A limit involving Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am reading Apostol's "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory". In Chapter 3, he defines Riemann Zeta Function, $\zeta(s)$, by the equation
\begin{equation}
\zeta(s) = 
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s} \quad \text{if } s > 1,
\end{equation}
and by the equation
\begin{equation}
\zeta(s) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} - \frac{x^{1 - s}}{1 -s} \right) \quad \text{if } 0 < s < 1.
\end{equation}
Then he derives the following asymptotic formulas.
\begin{equation} \label{harmonic_partial_sums}
\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} = \log x  + C + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{1/ns partial sums}
\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} = \zeta(s) + \frac{x^{1 - s}}{1 - s} + O(x^{-s}),
\end{equation}
where $C$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Looking at these formulas, one might suspect (naively) that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{s \to 1} \left( \zeta(s) + \frac{x^{1 - s}}{1 -s} \right) = \log x  + C.
\end{equation}
I tried to prove this by going back to the Abel summation formula but came across the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}} \, dt 
\end{equation}
whose limit does not exist as $s$ approaches $1$. I would highly appreciate if I could know whether the limit exists and if it exists what's its value.

Comment: The limit actually exists when $s\to1$ from the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Riemann zeta function has a simple pole at $s=1$, with residue $1$. If you take $x\gt0$ a real number, as I think you are, then: $$\begin{align}\lim_{s\to1}(\zeta(s)+x^{1-s}(1-s)^{-1})&=\lim_{s\to1}\left[\frac{x^{1-s}-1}{1-s}+\underset{\longrightarrow\gamma}{\underbrace{(\zeta(s)-(s-1)^{-1})}}\right]\\&\overset{L.H}=\gamma+\lim_{s\to1}\frac{(-\ln x)x^{1-s}}{-1}\\&=\ln(x)+\gamma\end{align}$$

As you expected, where the constant $C$ is the $\gamma$ the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant), or the first [Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

To see where these constants are coming from, I will reference for you an answer someone gave me a few months ago, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4331443/815585). No complex analysis is involved, really - you should only understand that "analytic continuation is unique" to understand why Conrad's zeta is the same as your zeta.

> $$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[-\ln n+\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{1}{m}\right]$$

Comment: Is there any elementary method to show the limit $\lim_{s \to 1} (\zeta(s) - (s-1)^{-1}) = \gamma$.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifZaheer Please see the answer I linked, it is as elementary as it could reasonably get. The thing is about the zeta function, there are a gazillion different representations, all equivalent on various different domains... sometimes other representations, like Conrad's, are more useful than Apostol's

Comment: @MuhammadAtifZaheer The main problem with *what*?

Comment: I think the main problem is with interchanging the following limits: $\lim_{s \to 1} \lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} + \frac{x^{1-s} - 1}{s - 1} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \lim_{s \to 1} \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} + \frac{x^{1-s} - 1}{s - 1}$.

Comment: The left hand side is $\lim_{s \to 1} \left \{ \zeta(s) - \frac{1}{s - 1} \right \}$ and the right hand side is $\gamma$.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifZaheer Agreed.